# Thead stops when another thread loop is waiting for a condition becomes true

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, loops

I want my code reading some conditions all the time, like reading position of an encoder, in a thread.

In paralel I need to do a command to my step motor go to a position and wait until this position is reached to set an output bit, "1". But when I start this "while the position is not reached" loop, it stops the thread that read position and atualize `txtPosX` or `txtPosY`.

I've tried `doevents()` and `thread.sleep(time)` to see if while it is sleeping, the other code execute some instructions from the other code that reads axis X and Y.

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf trdReadAxis)
End Sub

Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf trdStartJob)
End Sub

Private Delegate Sub delegate1()

Private Sub trdReadAxis()
    Do While true
        If InvokeRequired Then
            Dim d As New delegate1(AddressOf trdReadAxis)
            Invoke(d, Nothing)
        Else
            TPX = lib1.command("TELL POSITION X")
            TPY = lib1.command("TELL POSITION Y")
            txtPosX.text = TPX
            txtPosY.text = TPY
        End If
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub trdStartJob()
    If InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New delegate1(AddressOf trdStartJob)
        Invoke(d, Nothing)
    Else
        lib1.command("GO X TO POSITION 100")
        lib1.command("GO y TO POSITION 200")
        Dim contIntX As Integer = 100
        Dim contIntY As Integer = 200
        While movIsComp = False
            Thread.Sleep(200)
            If TPX = contIntX And TPY = contIntY Then
                movIsComp = True
            End If
            Application.DoEvents()
        End While
        #do other stuffs
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

It was expected that while the `trdStartJob()` is in the while loop waiting the position, `trdReadAxis()` atualize the textboxes. But what I've got was the `txtPosX` and `txtPosY` frozen.

So I need to wait the loop reach the condition of `"movIsComp = True"` to see the `txtBoxes` showing what they are supposed to show.

(sorry for my poor English, I'm trying to improve...)

Comment: That's because you have no threads. You delegate the work directly to the UI thread and just let your background threads terminate. You're only supposed to call `Invoke()` at the specific point in time where you actually want to _update_ the UI.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is that you should try to invoke as little as possible and only do it when it's _**really**_ necessary.